# ItemClickListener.onClick on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm having trying to work on a simple rss reader app for a local news website/paper I volunteer with and I'm trying to make an easy to use and a simple app for the site.

My main issue I'm encountering is that it keeps crashing **onClick** of an RSS feed item with "**null object reference**", I just want the app to open the default browser so it can load the article.

I'm linking the code as it is in a zip so anyone willing to help can check the code, I can't remember where I originally had the code from but I think I was following a video tutorial.  Mostly likely missing some of the code as I can't be sure if I finished watching it.

Link:
"https://www.dropbox.com/sh/imjgufrfpthbrql/AAA8MdTl-BAb7YzFqHswtYgxa?dl=0"

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have created method but forgot to initialize from activity or fragment.

```
`  public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

}`
```

Comment: I seem to have sorted it out now but I'm getting a Fatal Exception.  This is the line before the VM is closed "D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3d91840: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xab0bef40)
"

Comment: I also found this in the log "    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
"